# can you tell me what is the problem in my code

Tags: java, android

Am using horizontal scrollview in relative layout.But am not getting correct alignment of the edittext and buttons,and even am not getting the scroll view too.Please tell me what is wrong in my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/serviceslayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout1"
    android:background="#fff">

  <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#333333" android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0">

    <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/serviceslayout2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout1"
       android:background="#fff">

       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtTieover" android:textColor="#000" android:layout_height="65px" android:text="tie-over" android:layout_below="@+id/txtQuantity2" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="21dp" android:layout_marginTop="13dp"></TextView>

       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtQuantity2" android:textColor="#000" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Quantity" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerInParent="true"     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtTieover" android:layout_marginLeft="155dp" android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>

       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textColor="#000" android:layout_height="70px" android:text="insert" android:layout_below="@+id/txtTieover" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtTieover" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"></TextView>

       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:textColor="#000" android:layout_height="55px" android:text="direct bury" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtQuantity2" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"></TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please rephrase the question to reflect what the actual issue is (e.g. the layout issue), and post a screenshot or some other indicator of how the layout is currently working, vs. what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using `android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in horizontal scroll view is weird.
You'd better specify exact value or "fill_parent" to horizontal scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest you this really usefeul tutorial about View Hierarchy and ui profiling : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-tools-leveraging-the-hierarchy-viewer-for-ui-profiling/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your relative layout with id: `serviceslayout` as been aligned `toRightOf` another layout ( which im hoping has been declared since there is no layout with id `layout1` in your code given above).
Also, if your `layout1` (if defined) has in its layout_width as `fill_parent` then none of the above relative layouts will be visible...so make sure your layout1 isnt filling up the whole screen.
Hope this helps.